# adding javascript inside jsx array .map

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am very new to React typescripting and I would like to ask if its possible to add in javascript in jsx loops? I have been trying alot of methods but nothing seem to be working so I want to see if anyone has any suggestions or ideas.

```
{[...Array(7)].map((item,i) => (
        
      //basically i want to add my "if" condition here but i am not sure about the syntax


     <Tab id={"Item" + (number - i)} title={"Item " + (number - i )}></Tab>
         
  ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your map() arrow function is using parenthesis, which is shorthand for returning whatever is in the parenthesis. If you want other code in map() other than a return statement, use curly braces instead, like so:

```
{[...Array(7)].map((item,i) => { // change to curly brace
        
      // now you can write code here

     // We are no longer using the return shorthand so we explicitly state what we return
     return <Tab id={"Item" + (number - i)} title={"Item " + (number - i )}></Tab>
         
  })}
```